# Add list of models to Asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I want to assign a list of stores to a particular client, based on the Identity Model in MVC 5.  I want to be able to register a user/client using the default registration in the MVC 5 example code and be able to add a store, then assign the store to the user.

I'm having trouble being able to create a working viewmodel that incorporates the idenity model with a new list.

Here is what I have so far:

Model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        //[Required]
        [Display(Name = "Client/Company Name")]
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public List<Store> Stores { get; set; } 
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

I tried to add to the existing default dbcontext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }


        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

My controller blows up when I try to set my store clientname to the user clientname.  Clientname or any other property is unavailable for ApplicationUser.

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Stores
        public ActionResult Index(ClientStoreViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var clients = from s in db.Stores
                          join c in db.Users
                          on s.ClientName equals u.ClientName
                          select new ClientStoreViewModel() { Stores = s, Users = u };
            return View(clients);
        }
```

Store class:

```
public class Store
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //public int ClientId { get; set; }        
    [Display(Name = "Client Name")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Store Name")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Store Number")]
    public string StoreNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Store Login URL")]
    public string LoginURL { get; set; }
}
```

Finally my viewmodel:

```
public class ClientStoreViewModel
    {
        public ApplicationUser Users { get; set; }
        public Store Stores { get; set; }

        public ClientStoreViewModel()
        {
            Stores = new Store();
            Users = new ApplicationUser();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the store class?

Comment: Your database design looks off. Why have clientname in store model? If the store only has one client, add a navigation property for ApplicationUser. Second, you shouldn't need the join, just fetch the parent (ApplicationUser) and children (Stores) together: var clients = from c in db.Users.Include("Stores"). Then move the ApplicationUser properties you need for this view up a level. I would also recommend AutoMapper to map the entities into your ViewModel.

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks.  What do you mean by move ApplicationUser properties up a level?  Should I create a viewmodel with applicationuser propterties and store properties?  FYI, I had clientname as part of stores because I had a separate clients table that worked, but it wasnt linked to the registration model.  I've since removed it.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Exactly. Pick your entity model attributes that are used for that view, annotate them if needed and then use something like automapper to easily move it back for the update. https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/